# Can you forward params as an ActionController::Parameters object in a forms hidden_field?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, parameters, simple-form

Users apply filters in an index page and I need the filters' `params` to do some background jobs.

I can access the params after the filters are applied as you normally would, but when I try to forward the `request.params` to the controller action where I launch the background jobs, the params passed in the form's `hidden_field` no longer is an `ActionController::Parameters` object but a `String` instead, which I can't access as I would normally do by it's key.

*form:*

```
          <%= form_tag admin_users_on_demand_mass_emails_path, method: :get do %>
            <%= simple_fields_for :on_demand_email do |f| %>
              <%= hidden_field_tag :filters, params[:q].to_unsafe_h %>
                <%= f.input :email,
                as: :radio_buttons,
                collection: options_for_on_demand_emails %>
            <% end %>
            <%= submit_tag "Enviar emails", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
          <% end %>
```

*params before form send:*

```
<ActionController::Parameters {"q"=><ActionController::Parameters {"fname_or_lname_or_email_or_tax_id_number_or_legal_name_cont"=>"", "extra_params"=><ActionController::Parameters {"invoice_status"=>""} permitted: false>, "subscription_payment_type_eq"=>"", "address_province_eq"=>"", "subscription_status_eq"=>"cancelled", "created_at_gteq"=>"", "created_at_lteq"=>""} permitted: false>, "subscription_status_eq"=>"{}", "commit"=>"Filter", "controller"=>"admin/users", "action"=>"index"} permitted: false>
```

*becomes:*

```
{"filters"=>
  "{\"fname_or_lname_or_email_or_tax_id_number_or_legal_name_cont\"=>\"\", \"extra_params\"=>{\"invoice_status\"=>\"\"}, \"subscription_payment_type_eq\"=>\"\", \"address_province_eq\"=>\"\", \"subscription_status_eq\"=>\"cancelled\", \"created_at_gteq\"=>\"\", \"created_at_lteq\"=>\"\"}",
 "on_demand_email"=>"[FILTERED]",
 "commit"=>"Send emails"}
```

I've tried many different things such as passing `request.params.to_unsafe_h` (same result) and `params.require(:q).permit(params[:q].keys)` which results in an error in the view when `:q` is not present due to the `require`.

Is there any way to accomplish this or rebuild the params hash after it's been passed as a string?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `JSON.parse()` to convert them into hash like below,

```
{"filters"=>
  JSON.parse("{\"fname_or_lname_or_email_or_tax_id_number_or_legal_name_cont\"=>\"\", \"extra_params\"=>{\"invoice_status\"=>\"\"}, \"subscription_payment_type_eq\"=>\"\", \"address_province_eq\"=>\"\", \"subscription_status_eq\"=>\"cancelled\", \"created_at_gteq\"=>\"\", \"created_at_lteq\"=>\"\"}"),
 "on_demand_email"=>"[FILTERED]",
 "commit"=>"Send emails"}
```

Comment: Thank you. In the end I did `params.permit(q: params.dig(:q)&.keys`

Answer (score 0):

In the end I did params.permit(q: params.dig(:q)&.keys